# draw border using for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I'm trying to make a simple border using for loop. I don't get a proper result. Specifically, my right border is not shown. Please help.

```
const int width = 20;
const int height = 20;

void Drow() 
{
    system("cls");                      // clear the screan
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) 
    {
        cout << "*";                    // upper border
    }       

    for (int i = 0; i < height-2; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) 
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == width - 1)
            {
                cout << "*";            // left and right borders
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)     // lower border
        cout << "*";
}
```

Comment: Missing `<< std::endl` at some places?

Comment: Treat streams as if they were a toilet and filling them is a coded bowel movement and always remember to flush.

Comment: You can [try](https://ideone.com/5eppY4) using `string`s too ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second loop, you draw the borders but you forgot to draw the inside of your rectangle.

Add this to the `if`:

```
else {
    cout << " ";
}
```

As  πάντα ῥεῖ pointed out, you also forgot to use `endl` after the firt and last loops.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/065ZDu)

Comment: I did an edit just after your comment to the OP... Do you think there's more?

Comment: Well, we were overlapping in communication, but probably flesh out a more complete code sample for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I were feeling seriously masochistic, I'd do the job a bit differently.

My immediate reaction would be to write code more on this general order:

```
std::string h_border = std::string(width, '*' ) + "\n";
std::string v_border = "*" + std::string(width - 2,  ' ') +"*\n";

std::cout << h_border;
for (int i = 0; i < height - 2; i++)
    std::cout << v_border;
std::cout << h_border;
```